# Efficient way to Manage/Upload videos : Youtube API or Implementing own video upload

Tags: video, amazon-s3, youtube, upload, youtube-api

I am working on a website where users can upload videos. Maximum of 2000 videos might be uploaded per day. 
I'm planning to create a youtube channel and upload videos into the channel using youtube video upload API. 
Is it advisable to use Youtube for this purpose or should I work on own implementation, where I can upload the videos into s3. 
What would be the best approach and what are the limitations if I use Youtube for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should probably look into working on your own implementation. The reason why I am suggesting this is because with videos, and especially with the quantity of up to 2000 videos per day, it is hard to control/moderate the content of what videos will be uploaded to the channel. Any videos that go against YouTube's policies will put you in violation of [YouTube ToS](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms) and hence, the trouble will be yours to deal with as by allowing other users to upload these videos to the channel you are assuming responsibility for the content uploaded by others. Quoting the above mentioned link:

> 6(b). You shall be solely responsible for your own Content and the
>   consequences of submitting and publishing your Content on the Service.
>   You affirm, represent, and warrant that you own or have the necessary
>   licenses, rights, consents, and permissions to publish Content you
>   submit; and you license to YouTube all patent, trademark, trade
>   secret, copyright or other proprietary rights in and to such Content
>   for publication on the Service pursuant to these Terms of Service.

Having your own implementation will also give you the ability to scale if required and moderate those videos according to your requirements. You could however, still maintain a YouTube channel to upload "approved" content from your website in case you deem it to be necessary to your business use case.